# How to make the screen scroll top programmatically when keyboard is open in ionic

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Unable to scroll screen while keyboard is opened.I design a screen with labels, button and textarea. Textarea will be hidden for the first time, when user clicks a button, we are showing text area to the user.Now the issue is when i focus on textarea scrolling doesn't work and textarea is being covered by keyboard. 
What we observed is the problem with hide and show of textarea. If i put textarea static everything works as expected.

For some other reasons, I had this line in my code

> cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

These are the things I've tried and couldn't make it work

> $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollTop();
>
> $ionicScrollDelegate.ScrollBottom();
>
> $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo();
>
> $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBy();

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Give the x and y direction for your textview. When dismissing keyboard use it again and make co-ordinates (0,0).  This may help you.

Comment: Hi Pavan, Thank you for reply. We will try this in ios, but we need solution in ionic.